# There are two lines each side of periods in chrome URL section

Tags: google-chrome

I have a problem in URL section of Google Chrome. There are two lines each side of period's in URL section.[Image's here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otjyb.png)

How can i solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this purely visual or is it causing any functional issues? Your question doesn't say.

Comment: This is purely visual. It's happening when i select an URL.

Comment: What happens if you type manually the following URL: `www.google.com` - do you still see those lines?

Comment: Because of this website is accessed before and registered in my history, URL text will come as selected, then this problem is occur. If text is not selected, there is no problem at all.

Comment: I also tried Brave Browser that is most probably chrome based, The same problem happened with that too.

Comment: I understand that if you select your website, URL text will come as selected.  But if you type another URL, such as `www.google.com`, and then you select this new URL, what do you see?

Comment: It happens again. If URL is selected, It always happen.